# iOS Guidelines, Twitter Integration, StatusBar for network activity

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter, statusbar, ios5.1

I added the iOS 5 Twitter functionality into an App.
The App-Design is "without" statusbar. The guidlines from apple said, that an App with network  shouldn't hide the statusbar because the informations about the network activity.

Is it an reason for rejection to hide the statusbar with twitter integration?

Comment: "Should not" is a recommendation - you'll be fine hiding the statusbar even when network activity is ongoing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the similar problem. Don't worry, It is just fine If your App doesn't have a status bar, at all. It won't get your App rejected.

The thing is your App shouldn't have is inconsistent behavior. This is what, Apple guys gets annoyed by.

Good luck with your App :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always alleviate it by adding some kind of network activity indicator by yourself. The indicator in the statusbar does not trigger itself automatically anyway.